# Rspec expect method gives ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

Using Rails 5.2.3. Getting an error in Rspec. I believe the error is because I am mistyping or misusing the expect method.

```
Failure/Error: expect(SongsController.stub).to receive(:send_file)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
```

The code from the controller works in the browser.

```
send_file "amazing_grace.zip", :filename => "amazing_grace.zip", :url_based_filename => false, :type => "application/zip"
```

The test code is the following:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe 'Songs features' do
  describe 'viewing the index' do
    it 'downloads zip file from amazon' do
      expect(SongsController.stub).to receive(:send_file)
      visit('/songs/get_zip/1')
    end
  end
end
```

How would I correct the expect method, to no longer get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me. This passes.

```
expect_any_instance_of(SongsController).to receive(:send_file).with("amazing_grace_download.zip", "filename => "amazing_grace_download.zip", :url_based_filename => false, :type => "application/zip").and_call_original
visit('/songs/get_zip/1')
```

To make the test fail, all tests should fail before passing, I inserted a wrong argument in with().

```
expect_any_instance_of(SongsController).to receive(:send_file).with("xxx.zip", "filename => "amazing_grace_download.zip", :url_based_filename => false, :type => "application/zip").and_call_original).and_call_original
visit('/songs/get_zip/1')
```

This gave a

> Failure/Error: send_file "amazing_grace_download.zip", "filename =>
> "amazing_grace_download.zip", :url_based_filename => false, :type =>
> "application/zip".

But it also gave this message

> expected: ("xxx.zip", {:filename=>"amazing_grace_downloaded.zip",
> :type=>"application/zip", :url_based_filename=>false})
>
> got:
> ("amazing_grace_downloaded.zip",
> {:filename=>"amazing_grace_downloaded.zip", :type=>"application/zip",
> :url_based_filename=>false})

So, I know the test is running, because incorrect arguments means failure, and the test passes with correct arguments.